# WolframAlpha results for logic statement input

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra, equation

I was trying to simplify the following Boolean logic equation using [wolframalpha.com](http://wolframalpha.com).

> (not (A) and B and C) or (A and (not(B)) and C) or (A and B and not (C)) or (A and B and C)

When I entered it into the box, it spat out the following.
Image is a link.

[image: enter image description here[3]]

After showing me some simplifications of the logical statement, Wolf showed me something called truth density, which I am guessing is the ratio of true outputs to false inputs. I am mostly confused with the last two categories/results. What is a Boolean operator number, and why does the number 232 match my equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only 256 possible boolean operations with three inputs, because there are only 256 different ways you can put T's and F's in the result column of the truth table.

If you look at your truth table, and consider the result column. Instead of T and F, write the results as 1 and 0. Now consider that column of numbers as a binary number. It's value is

128 + 64 + 32 + 8 = 232